# Massive account suspensions

Tags: discussion

Hundreds of Bioacoustics Stack Exchange users received the following private message that announced the suspension of their account:

> Hello,
>
> We’re writing from the Stack Exchange Community Management Team
> with respect to your account. As you are likely aware, during the
> “Commitment” phase of the Area 51 process, we require that proposals
> receive at least 100 committers who have 200 reputation across the
> network.
>
> You may not be aware that we have certain network-wide
> policies that govern the voting systems on Stack Exchange. First among
> these is the principle: “Vote for the post, not the person.”
> Historically, we have interpreted this to mean that the posts you vote
> on should be discovered organically — not biased for or against any
> specific person. This policy captures a broad spectrum of behaviors.
> The following are examples of voting practices that violate Stack
> Exchange network policies:
>
> Voting repeatedly for a user by discovering
> posts through their profile.
> Voting for posts you are directly linked to > elsewhere (e.g., in Slack or by email)
>
> Deliberately voting in
> order to circumvent Stack Exchange system restrictions. For example,
> voting for a user’s posts only so that the user gains the privilege to
> comment.
>
> Creating additional accounts (“sockpuppets”) to upvote one’s
> own posts.
>
> Actively soliciting votes that do any of the above.
>
> Recently, we discovered a series of votes between committers to the
> Bioacoustics Area 51 proposal that appeared to violate our network
> policies. In this specific case, with the votes in question removed,
> the Bioacoustics Area 51 proposal would not have launched when it did:
> these voting violations materially changed the outcome of the
> proposal.
>
> We take this issue very seriously: attempts to circumvent
> the Area 51 process by voting for other specific users across the
> network is a violation of multiple core Stack Exchange policies.
>
> As a
> result of your active participation in these voting practices, your
> account has been suspended network-wide for 7 days. While you’re
> suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once
> the suspension ends. And, once the suspension ends, for the most part,
> you may return to the site and participate as normal.
>
> However, Stack
> Exchange does not allow users who have been suspended in the year
> preceding an election to become moderators on the network. As a
> result, when we open nominations for the Bioacoustics election, you
> will no longer be eligible to nominate yourself in this election.
> Although this notice is quite serious, we hope this message does not
> discourage you from contributing to Bioacoustics Stack Exchange in the
> future — in compliance with our voting policies.
>
> We appreciate and
> respect your enthusiasm for contributing to the Stack Exchange
> network. During the course of our investigation, we discovered a
> significant number of training and guidance materials for folks in
> your field to help them grow familiar with the Stack Exchange format.
> We commend this work and have very real respect for the time and
> energy you’ve put into building this site.
>
> We look forward to your
> future contributions to the Stack Exchange network.
>
> Thanks, Stack
> Exchange Community Management Team

I write this message on behalf of many of them in addition to just myself. We totally understand that SE sometimes has to suspend accounts but here it seems that SE has suddenly over-reacted. The way SE decided to suspend hundreds of users is quite obscure but I believe SE may have trusted the quality of their detection algorithm too much? SE did not providing any evidence or examples of how suspended users violated the CoC. By not giving users detailed knowledge on how they broke the rules, how are they supposed to course correct? Additionally, this mass suspension action, which has no mechanism for users to appeal, is unfriendly and we have lost many users who were using the site in good faith but are now turned off by this and leaving the site.

Organizing ourselves in our small community to promote and energize a Beta site does not mean we want to cheat. On one hand, 1) SE pushes us to vote as much as possible to reach the metric requirements, 2) SE awards us when we vote more (e.g. Vox Populi badge), and on the other hand, SE suspends our account WITHOUT ANY WARNING (at least as far as I am concerned) when we apparently upvote too often for the same persons. Many other reasons other than "cheating" can explain that, including the fact that 2 members may share common issues/knowledge that will logically lead to inter-votes. In any case, we don't vote for persons, we vote for the quality of individual posts.

I think that SE is at least as responsible as the Bioacoustics members for what it is going on, however, unfortunately, they put all the responsibilities on the members. A warning could be far more efficient than a direct suspension, which will discourage many of us. For instance, SE suspended 5 (and most active) editors out of 6 (https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all)!
Last but not least, SE did this in the middle of a moderator election which they then cancelled...

As far as we are all concerned, I think this sudden "authoritarian" response is not respectful to the amount of work all of us have put in during the last few months. We would appreciate explicit evidence and documentation that warranted this behavior and how best to move forward in regaining users we have lost from this unfair action.

Comment: Totally agree, @Carly. 100% behind this. We have little transparency and a strong, clever, and giving community. All of this drama is such a confusing distraction.

Comment: @NikeDattani that might 'seem' humorous - but that's ... a rather serious accusation. I'd note this post was linked on main meta, and its a much more honest and direct response than we'd get. The community team has a stake in the network's constituent sites succeeding, as much as us random SE denizens.

Comment: Right now no one from the Bioacoustics can vote or post because of their accounts being suspended....there would be dozens more upvotes. Convenient, I agree.

Comment: *A warning could be far more efficient than a direct suspension, which will discourage many of us.* – As a moderator of one of the affected sites, I would like to comment on this: As early as April, we noticed problematic coordinated activities from a dozen people (who turned out to be Bioacoustics supporters). They all received warnings/suspensions or other clear signals such as post deletions, some of them twice. Naturally, we could only warn those whom we knew to be involved, but plenty of people were warned and had ample time to share their experience.

Comment: Not everyone received a warning before their suspension, I've talked to some people who did not.

Comment: Yep, I was suspended for "activities not on this site", with no warning. My last SE action outside of this forum was a single vote on march 28, and an answer on Aug 10, 2021. 
Peculiar to have that as grounds for suspension. Seems someone at SE just presses "ctrl+a" and then hit "suspend".

Comment: @Rasmus that is super frustrating and it seems like you may be a good candidate to appeal, if you are willing to go through that process - [this post](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173/deferral-of-inaugural-election-and-next-steps-for-the-bioacoustics-community) has a link to the "Contact Us" form where you can appeal

Answer (score 13):

I want to start by highlighting a bit you quoted from the mod message users were sent:

> We appreciate and respect your enthusiasm for contributing to the Stack Exchange network. During the course of our investigation, we discovered a significant number of training and guidance materials for folks in your field to help them grow familiar with the Stack Exchange format. We commend this work and have very real respect for the time and energy you’ve put into building this site.
>
> We look forward to your future contributions to the Stack Exchange network.

**The Community Management Team fully appreciates the level of involvement and effort needed to get a new community off the ground, and to go through the Area 51 process. As mentioned in the mod message, we also appreciate that you put effort into getting new folks acquainted with the Stack Exchange platform and how it works.** This situation is in no way ideal for any of the parties involved, and it gives us no pleasure to have to take such widespread enforcement action affecting such a big portion of the folks who’ve established themselves as a core part of this community.

We completely understand that this situation is frustrating, causes confusion, and is a heavy blow for this community. We also recognize that these actions may make parts of the community feel unappreciated, and that your efforts to establish a successful community may feel like they are going to waste. The actions undertaken by the Community Management Team in this instance were *not* taken lightly — in fact, the reason [the election was canceled](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/144/70) was *precisely* so we could take the time to fully investigate the circumstances surrounding the issues we’d found, so the results of that investigation could fully inform any actions we’d need to take.

### Clarifying the moderator message

Given the confusion expressed by many of the users who’ve responded to messages they were sent, we would like to clarify one critical point with regards to the nature of the infringing voting behaviors. To clarify: **the problematic votes were not cast on this site, but rather on other sites on the Stack Exchange network.** It is not abnormal that, in the early stages of a new site, a lot of cross-voting takes place between the most engaged users — especially given the site’s success depends on that. **What *is* abnormal and problematic, however, is to coordinate handing out votes with the explicit intention of meeting reputation-based privilege thresholds, in an attempt to aid the proposal’s progression through the Area 51 stages** — and the evidence we’ve uncovered clearly demonstrates that this behavior took place.

One additional clarification - the number of users suspended does not number in the hundreds. In total, we took around 90 actions - around 70 suspensions, and 20 warnings.

#### The story – or, the parts we can share

We recognize that in the absence of complete information, it can be frustrating to understand what’s happening. We have an obligation to protect user privacy, but here’s the part of the story we can share.

Some time ago, multiple moderation teams across the Stack Exchange network brought an irregular voting issue to our attention. These irregular votes were disruptive to normal activities on their sites. It’s typical for moderators to call our attention to issues like this when they lack the tools to investigate fully on-site — such as when irregular voting spans many sites on the network. Moderators only have insight into voting patterns on their *own* sites. The need for a more wide-ranging investigation and the potential need for action across multiple sites necessarily involved the Community Management Team.

Once the investigation concluded, we issued suspensions where the number of involved votes was significant, and we issued warnings where the number of votes was minor. None of these actions was undertaken by automated systems, nor detected by automatic algorithms. To further ensure that the enforcement actions were correctly taken, we had multiple Community Managers from the team involved, cross-checking and validating each others’ work, up to and including the involvement of our VP of Community. We are confident in the outcome of this investigation, but because the number of involved users is high, it is possible that some users may have received a message erroneously — however, we expect this number (if any) to be very small.

The Community Management Team is fully aware of these actions’ potential impacts on this community’s health and chances of success, and we carefully weighed the balance of harms to find a sensible path forward. Given the evidence we uncovered during our investigation, we feel that the actions taken were proportional to the offense, and that we have followed typical moderation guidance on Stack Exchange.

Finally, a couple of notes: it is a general policy on the Stack Exchange to not debate **individual** user suspensions publicly on Meta, especially when the involved users are still suspended and cannot take part in the conversation. Additionally, while we understand the concerns surrounding transparency in this situation, pointing users who violated rules to the exact votes that broke the rules is not something we usually do. Unfortunately, this means follow-up questions to the effect of “can you show me the votes that caused my message/suspension?” are likely to stay unresponded-to, both in the moderator message and in public.

### Where this community goes from here

We know that this can be overwhelming and could be demoralizing. But with all that being said, please remember that all is not lost. To highlight another bit of the quoted text you posted:

> Although this notice is quite serious, we hope this message does not discourage you from contributing to Bioacoustics Stack Exchange in the future — in compliance with our voting policies.

This was written sincerely! We recognize some *will* be put off and driven away by this situation, but that is *not* the intention of our actions. The goal of any message or suspension is to provoke change; **not to punish**. Such actions exist to provide the gentlest appropriate correction that we believe can remit the situation, while remaining consistent with prior similar interventions (where they exist) and staying true to the spirit of the rules. Stack Exchange does not hold grudges, [nor do we keep public records of suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293213/) — we *know* that past offenders can turn into healthy contributors to our communities, and, indeed, have instances where folks who’ve been suspended have later become moderators somewhere on the network. In one week’s time, we hope the vast majority of the users who were suspended do return to the site and continue to contribute, bearing this guidance in mind.

**We still plan to hold an election to find your inaugural moderators — stay tuned for an announcement early next week — and we are confident this community can still be healthy and thrive.** While [the users suspended will *not* be able to run in this election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), there are still many viable election candidates within the community who we hope will nominate themselves for the position. **The success of this site rests in the outcome of that election, and at least 3 moderators are required for it to be considered a success — for that reason, we encourage anyone who is eligible to nominate for the position once the new election date is set and nominations are open.**

Comment: "Not a punishment" You have caused a lot of damage and mistrust in this community with these actions. Several colleagues have deleted accounts and more will undoubtedly follow if you carry on with your policy for banning folk from the moderator elections. As what you accuse us of happened before this site was even created and has not happened since, this is by definition a punishment, because it does nothing but cause harm to this site. This was not the way to treat this community.

Comment: As mentioned in the messages and in the post, the aim of our actions was not to discourage further participation — we understand our actions cause frustration, and although they were not an easy decision to come to, they were the ones the circumstances and evidence led us to take.

Comment: @JamieMacaulay You're correct that it hasn't happened _since_ the site launched, but these votes occurred weeks before the suspensions were issued, and had a negative impact on many sites across the network. That negative impact does not evaporate just because the site ultimately launched and the impetus to vote illegitimately disappeared. So our response is ultimately protective of the network as a whole. Suspensions are often issued to ask users to step back for a bit and re-evaluate _how_ they engage with the site, particularly when it is causing problems network-wide.

Comment: Sure, I get it. We broke the rules so you have to make an example of us. It’s the way you went about it, without warning, without trying to work with the community for an explanation (that has now been provided). Cutting out almost all the moderators in the election too. I just can’t see a justification for cost/benefit of that approach but hey, I’m also not running a giant q&a website. Fingers crossed the site moves on from all this.

Comment: @JamieMacaulay I think that is an unfair characterization. The CMs very much want this site to succeed. I understand the sentiment that wants to attribute a malicious motive to the suspensions, but I think nothing is further from the truth. StackExchange could freely delete this site or any accounts if they wanted you to leave. They acted in response to a very large voting network *without which this site might not exist*, yet they keep staff resources supporting this site. Suspensions without warning are rare here; that indicates the severity of the offense, not the callousness of staff.

Comment: Fraudulent voting broke the step where a proposal is supposed to backed by users with familiarity with how SE works, by asking or answering questions around the network. Instead, a bunch of new people brought to SE by this proposal had their first experience gaining reputation through fraudulent voting. This was likely a confusing arrival to other sites on the network, where users had their reputation gains reversed or content deleted for fraud.

Comment: I do not understand an argument that because candidates for moderator were involved, somehow SE should have taken a lighter approach. Moderators are trusted with private user data and with a lot of responsibility in setting the direction of a site. They are often expected to make decisions specifically when a clear written guideline is not available. As JNat points out, there are many potential candidates in this community that were not suspended.

Comment: @BryanKrause "*I understand the sentiment that wants to attribute a malicious motive to the suspensions*" I have not read this anywhere. This bumbled situation arose because the investigation into the fraudulent votes  began *during* the election process. At least that is my impression. If the investigation had already been in process *before* the election began nobody among the staff would have allowed the nomination phase to go underway.

Comment: The investigation and the suspensions should have concluded *before* 5 users volunteered.  It didn't happen because someone at SE finally woke up to the fact that several mods across the network had informed the team, *months earlier*, that something was not quite right with number of votes being cast in their sites. Community managers need to be updated on a regular basis, moderators across the network need to insist that the team responds sooner not later to any concerns raised.

Comment: The breakdown of communication between sites that are outside the big five–Stack Overflow, SuperUser, Unix & Linux, Ask Ubuntu, and Mathematics, and the team of CMs is nothing new. There are too many sites and too few CMs, and CMs who rarely if ever participate on the smaller meta sites. They probably don't have time, but it means that when something does happen, users on smaller sites will view them as uncaring strangers.

Comment: But the fact remains that there was *no warning* to the suspended (me one of them). With no examples given, and no warnings when supposedly breaking rules, it leaves us no way to learn what was done wrong. 

I note the sentence:
"To clarify: the problematic votes were not cast on this site, but rather on other sites on the Stack Exchange network." 
To my best knowledge my only activity on SE was *on this site* during this period (since Aug 10 2021), so being suspended because of activity not on this site seems puzzling, if not down-right a lie.

Comment: @Rasmus From this post: "What is abnormal and problematic, however, is to coordinate handing out votes with the explicit intention of meeting reputation-based privilege thresholds, in an attempt to aid the proposal’s progression through the Area 51 stages".

Comment: @Rasmus From the mod message posted in the question here: "Voting repeatedly for a user by discovering posts through their profile. ... Voting for posts you are directly linked to > elsewhere (e.g., in Slack or by email) ... 

Deliberately voting in order to circumvent Stack Exchange system restrictions. For example, voting for a user’s posts only so that the user gains the privilege to comment. ...

Creating additional accounts (“sockpuppets”) to upvote one’s own posts. ...

Actively soliciting votes that do any of the above."

Comment: Since this whole thing was about votes occurring in order to boost this Area51 proposal prior to it [reaching Beta](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32767/congratulations-to-bioacoustics-on-completing-the-commitment-phase), the offending activity certainly occurred before the narrow recent window you're talking about.

Comment: @BryanKrause Again, I have not participated in any of those activities. Pre the bioacoustics beta my last activity was last summer, but they still suspended me (and others I belive). Hence, the point stands, we were suspended with no warning for not having done anything (I've been on SE for ~6 years with no suspensions).

Comment: @Rasmus You can possibly reply to the message and ask for clarification, though the staff isn't going to discuss your case publicly here per policy and as JNat already mentioned they don't typically point to specific votes. As they've described, this wasn't an automated or capricious action but something carefully studied where patterns emerged. Suspensions only went to accounts with the most evidence, others with lesser involvement were only warned.

Comment: @Rasmus as an outsider without knowing any details and reasons, I'd assume the suspension is related to the [-200 rep voting correction on your SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7409197/rasmus?tab=reputation). Whether it's related to this case or not, who knows but the staff.

Comment: @AndrewT. I saw that too and that makes sense, except Rasmus only received 3 upvotes (30 rep points) since the start of the year/when this proposal was in the commitment phase.

Comment: @AndrewT. that -200 was because of my suspension (that's the reason given on my account) and thus not the cause of it. Also this is not because of my actions, but because others have voted on my contributions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: @Rasmus Based *entirely* on public information: The -200 voting corrected reversal on your SO account on 2022-08-26 *had nothing to do with your suspension for this issue*. The suspensions for the issues here were applied prior to 2022-08-19 (this question's date). Your reversal was 7+ days later. Your voting correction was for serial voting *to* your account in 2018 (only possibility) by at least 5 other users. >= 5 accounts is known because there were 5 sets of serial votes all on 4 posts. 5 votes on each of 4 posts requires >= 5 users, which tracks as 5 votes * 4 posts * 10 rep = 200 rep.

Comment: @Rasmus You appear to have misunderstood [the page you linked to](//stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed). Users are *not* suspended for nor at fault for being the *target* of serial voting, unless they participated in getting the votes (e.g. created sockpuppet accounts to upvote their own posts). You've mentioned one suspension for the reason described in the question here, which was *not* because of that voting correction/reversal. Presuming you have no other, more recent suspension or moderator message, then I'd assume you were merely the target of the voting and without fault.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the correction, but this leaves me even more confused in regards to the suspension.

Comment: Rasmus - I've heard many stories like this too from colleagues.  Although some of us are guilty of up-voting folk in the community, many were not. I also cannot get over the way this was handled and the needless damage that was caused - I clearly did not understand SE's approach to these sites and have deleted my account as I do not wish to participate further - except that  I need approval to do so (there is definitely a bit of irony there) @JNat I would be grateful if you could help delete my account (JamieMacaulay) - it's been 5 days now since I requested it?

Comment: @Rasmus `To my best knowledge my only activity on SE was on this site during this period (since Aug 10 2021), so being suspended because of activity not on this site seems puzzling` If your activity was this limited, it's possible your suspension was inappropriate especially if you received no prior warning. Staff *do* make mistakes, so it's worth spending some time composing an email and explaining in detail (include links etc.) why you think an error was committed when your account was suspended.  https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: @Rasmus if you do appeal, please let is know if it is successful (if you are comfortable with that) here or over on that chat

Comment: Hi, I have appealed and I'm waiting for a response. Happy to share results of the appeal (unless asked not to by moderators)

Comment: (1/2) From SE:
"... we included some data from the 2018 attempt to launch the Bioacoustics proposal, where similar targeted voting occurred. [...] there haven’t been any targeted votes for your account since that proposal. However, because the voting that took place in 2018 passed the threshold against which we evaluated suspensions for the current proposal, your account was included in this group of suspensions due to the votes from 2018. Additionally, those votes elevated your account over the reputation requirement needed for the current proposal to advance past the Commitment phase."

Comment: (2/2)  No concrete examples were given to me, and as far as I can see from my past activities, I had no activities in 2018, nor have I ever received a warning. Maybe area 51 activity is not shown, but regardless, I have asked them to provide more details, as I do not remember engaging in "targeted" voting at any time (it's 5 years ago!).

Comment: @Rasmus thanks for sharing. It seems to me like you may have been the recipient of targeted voting but you did not yourself do that or break that part of the code of conduct (an innocent bystander of sorts). I was part of the proposal in 2018 but it was much less organized in that first attempt so I don't remember any sort of targeted voting efforts (nor do I remember you from it or know you outside of SE, if that makes you feel any better!)

Comment: Their reply to me asking for clarification and lack of warning: "Our investigation found that the actions in question did not fit the definition of organic voting but were systematic in nature, and therefore were deemed as targeted."