# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/election/3) (well, *technically* #3, but really your first election) on Bioacoustics has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Amandine Gasc]

[image: Carly Batist]

[image: Dan Stowell]

They will be forming [the site' initial crew](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6162646620438528).

Comment: Congratulations everyone. Including Taiki, you did well as well!

Comment: youuuhouuuuuuu!

Comment: Thank you all for your willingness to help our community!

Comment: Calling this "election #3" is confusing and will only get more and more confusing over time (e.g. users that join 5 years from now could wonder why the third election is called "election #5"). Is it necessary to number them that way? If so I'll write here that [election 1 was cancelled](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/144/33) and [election 2 was "deferred"](https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/33) so that anyone else that's as confused as I was, doesn't have to do any detective work.

Answer (score 6):

Yay! Thank you all for your volunteered services and for all you already do, and will do, for the site!